# Adding column_name != 3 returns much fewer results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this database query:

```
select      scheduled_hike_id 
        ,   hike_date 
        ,   hike_title 
        ,   hike_group_id 
        ,   hike_privacy 
        ,   hike_description 
        ,   DAYOFMONTH(hike_date) 
        ,   DAYNAME(hike_date) 
        ,   YEAR(hike_date) 
        ,   MONTH(hike_date) 
from        scheduled_hikes 
where       is_cancelled is null 
and         hike_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
and         show_on_home_page = 1  
order by    hike_date limit 4
```

It returns what I expected.  When I add a clause "and hike_privacy != 3" it returns MUCH fewers results.

The other values in the column are NULL, 1, 2

Any ideas why the != 3 isn't working as I expected? Also, <3 is giving similarly unexpected results.  I am using MySQL

Comment: You have `LIMIT 4` in your query. What number of records did you expect in return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hike_privacy is `null`, it won't match `hike_privacy != 3`.

Try: `and (hike_privacy != 3 or hike_privacy is null)`

Nulls never match non "null style" comparisons.

**Note:** Make sure you use brackets around your "OR" terms! In SQL, OR takes precedence, so without the brackets it would parsed as if it was coded like this (note the position of the brackets):

```
where   (       is_cancelled is null 
            and hike_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
            and show_on_home_page = 1 
            and hike_privacy != 3
        ) 
or      hike_privacy is null
```

which is quite different from what we want, which is:

```
where       is_cancelled is null 
        and hike_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
        and show_on_home_page = 1 
        and (       
                    hike_privacy != 3 
                or hike_privacy is null
            )
```

Answer (score 3):

try `and (hike_privacy IS NULL OR hike_privacy != 3)`

Comment: dont know why someone downvoted this, ic3b3rg is correct. Null is not less then or greater then any number or not equal to - it is the absence of value

Comment: WARNING! "OR" takes precedence in SQL, so the "or hike_privacy != 3" will stand alone as a match - ie it will be (the entire where clause except "hike_privacy != 3") OR (hike_privacy != 3)

Comment: @Erik I downvoted it - read my comment. It's basically "wrong"

Comment: @Bohemian I guess that was your downvote then... I realized my mistake as soon as I posted and edited accordingly... awfully quick on that downvote

Comment: Cool! Unfortunately I can't remove my downvote becasue it's been too long. (If you edit it, I can tho - I'll check it in a few minutes)